# How do we perform swap operation in conflict-serializability?

Tags: database, conflict-serializability

Assume I have the following concurrent transactions:

```
----------------------
|Ti        | Tj      |
----------------------         
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
|          | read(Q) |
----------------------
| read(Q)  |         |
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
```

If we draw the precedence-graph, we'll see that it is not conflict-serializable. Since the graph will be cyclic. The reason is:

```
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
```

From the book: "Database System Concepts - 6th edition" [source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EZRc.png)

> If a schedule S can be transformed into a schedule S' by a series of swaps of non-conflicting instructions, we say that S and S' are conflict equivalent. We say that a schedule S is conflict serializable if it is conflict equivalent to  a serial schedule.

Now, what does this `swap` means?

Can I do something like:

```
----------------------
|Ti        | Tj      |
----------------------         
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
| read(Q)  |         |
----------------------
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
|          | read(Q) |
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
```

Or can I change the order?

```
----------------------
|Ti        | Tj      |
----------------------         
| read(Q)  |         |
----------------------
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
|          | read(Q) |
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
```

Regards

P.S. I looked at [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823030/what-is-the-difference-between-conflict-serializable-and-conflict-equivalent) but it is not explaining the `swap` operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`swap` means moving the statements to the desired place. Therefore `swap` is a trivial terminology for detecting conflict-serializability. However, `swaps of non-conflicting instruction` is important.

> Can I do something like:

```
----------------------
|Ti        | Tj      |
----------------------         
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
| read(Q)  |         |
----------------------
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
|          | read(Q) |
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
```

No we can't do the above operation. Since the operation on `Q` ends at the end of the transaction. Swapping should not change the order.

> Or can I change the order?

No changing the order is not permitted. Changing the order means updating the transaction which is not permitted unless the transaction is aborted.

[image]

Since we have a cycle, the operation is not conflict serializable. Serializable is important for Consistency and Isolation requirements. As we can wee the problem is caused by the last sentence of the `Ti`

### What happens if we remove the last sentence of the `Ti`?

```
----------------------
|Ti        | Tj      |
----------------------         
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
|          | read(Q) |
----------------------
| read(Q)  |         |
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
|          | write(Q)|
----------------------
```

Now the schedule becomes the conflict-serializable.

### How about swapping?

If the situation is similar to the below:

```
----------------------
|Ti        | Tj      |
----------------------         
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
|          | read(W) |
----------------------
| read(Q)  |         |
----------------------
|          | write(W)|
----------------------
|          | write(W)|
----------------------
```

Then we can swap `read(Q)` with `read(W)`:

```
----------------------
|Ti        | Tj      |
----------------------         
| write(Q) |         |
----------------------
| read(Q)  |         |
----------------------
|          | read(W) |
----------------------
|          | write(W)|
----------------------
|          | write(W)|
----------------------
```

### Interpretation

The transaction `Ti` starts with writing to Q column without reading the `Q`'s current value. This might cause a violation if there is a trigger checking the database. Then `Ti` and `Tj` both do `read(Q)` operation. Suddenly `Tj` starts writing. Then `Ti` writes without waiting `Tj` to commit. Therefore by looking at the current state, we can say the situation is troubled.